# Errno 13 Permission denied. in jupyter notebook, UBUNTU

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I'm newly using 'UBUNTU in windows' and opened jupyter notebook inside UBUNTU, make new python3 file and try to load a file named 'Elliptic_main.py'. However, the following code

```
%load Elliptic_main.py
```

gives error messages

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-69cbacf526f9> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('load', 'Elliptic_main.py')

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2129                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2130             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2131                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2132             return result
   2133 

<decorator-gen-47> in load(self, arg_s)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/code.py in load(self, arg_s)
    333         search_ns = 'n' in opts
    334 
--> 335         contents = self.shell.find_user_code(args, search_ns=search_ns)
    336 
    337         if 's' in opts:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in find_user_code(self, target, raw, py_only, skip_encoding_cookie, search_ns)
   3263             if os.path.isfile(tgt):                        # Read file
   3264                 try :
-> 3265                     return openpy.read_py_file(tgt, skip_encoding_cookie=skip_encoding_cookie)
   3266                 except UnicodeDecodeError :
   3267                     if not py_only :

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/utils/openpy.py in read_py_file(filename, skip_encoding_cookie)
     74     A unicode string containing the contents of the file.
     75     """
---> 76     with open(filename) as f:   # the open function defined in this module.
     77         if skip_encoding_cookie:
     78             return "".join(strip_encoding_cookie(f))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py in open(filename)
    450     detect_encoding().
    451     """
--> 452     buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    453     try:
    454         encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Elliptic_main.py'
```

I think this is an issue for UBUNTU, but I'm not sure. Anyone has same issue? Thanks for any helps

---

typing

```
ls -l Elliptic_main.py
```

gives the following message:

```
---------- 1 sungha sungha 1418 Sep 14 13:54 Elliptic_main.py
```

here sungha is my user name.

Comment: How are the permissions for `Elliptic_main.py` set? You can find out by typing `ls -l Elliptic_main.py` in the terminal

Comment: I added it on the question because I cannot write it in comment section

Comment: And you shouldn't. If someone asks for more information in comments on this site, always add them to your question with the correct formatting and then make a comment that you did so.

Comment: there are no permissions set. try `chmod 777 Elliptic_main.py` to set them. See [FilePermissions](https://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4124/) for some background - you can use 666 if you do not want to use shebangs in it (and dont mind _this_ number ;) ).  This will lead to you, your group and others be able to do read(4),write(2),execute(1) (additive = 7) it.

Comment: It works! Thanks for helps, guys!

Comment: Also thanks for nice background link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `ls` output

```
---------- 1 sungha sungha 1418 Sep 14 13:54 Elliptic_main.py
```

Notice the

```
----------
```

part that shows which permissions are set ([see for example in this wiki for further details](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes))
In your case you don't have ANY permissions on that file which is why you see `Permission error`

Try

```
chmod 600 # in case sungha is your username
chmod 666 # otherwise
```

Check the manpage of `chmod` by typing `man chmod` in your terminal for further details on what the difference is between the two